# Fiz uma captura de campos do bd e dá esse erro

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, codeigniter, post

Depois q eu coloquei esse codigo abaixo ....

```
         $capturaValorTotal = $_POST['valor'];
         $capturaValorPagar = $_POST['valor-pagar'];

         $valorDevido = $capturaValorTotal - $capturaValorPagar;

         $inserindoBanco = "INSERT INTO `clientes` (`saldoDevedor`) VALUES ('".$valorDevido."')";

         $executandoQuery = mysql_query($inserindoBanco);
```

Aconteceu esses erros abaixo ...

> A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: valor-pagar

Filename: controllers/financeiro.php

Line Number: 355
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/molu/public_html/ossystem/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 675
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/molu/public_html/ossystem/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 542

Lembrando que é um sistema feito em codeigniter, com POO. Todos os campos citados acima foram inseridos no banco de dados. No Models fiz o select dos campos que preciso (caso precisam, eu posto aqui tbm o Models.)

Meu intuito é apenas fazer uma alteração no sistema, para que qdo o usuário receba parte de um pagamento, o sistema registre o "faltante" no campo saldoDevedor da tabela cliente.

Espero que consegui explicar minha dúvida.

Comment: Ponha `var_dump($_POST)` no inicio do teu código, e veja se realmente a chave "valor-pagar" existe.

Comment: Se você está usando o codeigniter pq está usando `$_POST` direto? deveria usar a classe `input`. Sem falar na função obsoleta `mysql_query()`

Comment: rray, sou um iniciante no PHP. Estou começando e tenho esse sistema o conhecido MAP OS (aquele de Ordens de Serviço). Como estou sem $capital$Nenhum, e preciso fazer essas mudanças urgentes, eu tenho que por a mão no código. Más não conheço muito do codeigniter, embora eu esteja gostando. Se vocês puderem me indicar algum site ou curso de codeigniter agradeceria. Más quanto a esse problema, como eu faria esse input? O $this->db->input-post é o mesmo que o _$POST()? Tive pesquisando mas não consegui achar a resposta ou não consegui entender essa questão!

Comment: William Novak, coloquei o var_dump e gerou esse erro:

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: valor-pagar

Filename: controllers/financeiro.php

Line Number: 355
NULL
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/molu/public_html/ossystem/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 675

Comment: Más na VIEW existe o campo valor-pagar, que está na for (for="valor-pagar"). Agora o que não estou entendendo é: se lá na view tem esse campo, como vou "declarar" aqui na controller.

Comment: Até seguindo a dica do RRAY, eu fiz o $this->input->post('valor'); e $this->input->post('valor-pagar');, substituindo o _$POST(). Embora aquele monte de erro não apareceu mais, más ficou a tela toda branca (o que me preocupou mais). E no banco nada foi gravado... tipow.. aquele resultado da "continha" que deveria ser gravada no banco, não foi gravada. Vou postar o código novamente....

Comment: $capturaValorTotal => $this->input->post('valor');
             $capturaValorPagar => $this->input->post('valor-pagar');
             
             $valorDevido = $capturaValorTotal - $capturaValorPagar;
             
             $inserindoBanco = "INSERT INTO `clientes` set `saldoDevedor`='".$valorDevido."'";
             
             $executandoQuery = mysql_query($inserindoBanco);

Answer (score 1):

eu vejo alguns problemas ai

1)troca sua linha do insert por esta

```
$inserindoBanco = "INSERT INTO `clientes` set `saldoDevedor`='".valorDevido."'";
```

2) valor-pagar não esta definido

3) vc esta fazendo algum output de informação antes de alguma header ou esta setando 2 headers na mesma página. Seria interessante você disponibilizar o cod todo para verificação.

Comment: Jasar Orion. Tbm fiz essa mudança, más não foi gravado nada no banco. Ali no ".valorDevido." coloquei o $ e mesmo assim não deu certo.